# Bing-Map-API what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#, wpf, bing-maps

I am trying for my school to use the Bing Map API and use GeocodeAdress. I build this application: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd221354.aspx and the problem is I get this error every time.

it is at line 62: this method: GeocodeServiceClient geocodeService = new GeocodeServiceClient();

!InvalidOperationException was unhandled
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll

Additional information: An endpoint configuration section for contract 'GeocodeService.IGeocodeService' could not be loaded because more than one endpoint configuration for that contract was found. Please indicate the preferred endpoint configuration section by name.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

using BingMapsSample.GeocodeService;
using BingMapsSample.SearchService;
using BingMapsSample.ImageryService;
using BingMapsSample.RouteService;

namespace BingMapsSample
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private String GeocodeAddress(string address)
    {
        string results = "";
        string key = "Validate Bing Map Education Code";
        GeocodeRequest geocodeRequest = new GeocodeRequest();

        // Set the credentials using a valid Bing Maps key
        geocodeRequest.Credentials = new GeocodeService.Credentials();
        geocodeRequest.Credentials.ApplicationId = key;

        // Set the full address query
        geocodeRequest.Query = address;

        // Set the options to only return high confidence results 
        ConfidenceFilter[] filters = new ConfidenceFilter[1];
        filters[0] = new ConfidenceFilter();
        filters[0].MinimumConfidence = GeocodeService.Confidence.High;

        // Add the filters to the options
        GeocodeOptions geocodeOptions = new GeocodeOptions();
        geocodeOptions.Filters = filters;
        geocodeRequest.Options = geocodeOptions;

        // Make the geocode request
        GeocodeServiceClient geocodeService = new GeocodeServiceClient();
        GeocodeResponse geocodeResponse = geocodeService.Geocode(geocodeRequest);

        if (geocodeResponse.Results.Length > 0)
            results = String.Format("Latitude: {0}\nLongitude: {1}",
              geocodeResponse.Results[0].Locations[0].Latitude,
              geocodeResponse.Results[0].Locations[0].Longitude);
        else
            results = "No Results Found";

        return results;
    }

    private string ReverseGeocodePoint(string locationString)
    {
        string results = "";
        string key = "Validate Bing Map Education Code";
        ReverseGeocodeRequest reverseGeocodeRequest = new ReverseGeocodeRequest();

        // Set the credentials using a valid Bing Maps key
        reverseGeocodeRequest.Credentials = new GeocodeService.Credentials();
        reverseGeocodeRequest.Credentials.ApplicationId = key;

        // Set the point to use to find a matching address
        GeocodeService.Location point = new GeocodeService.Location();
        string[] digits = locationString.Split(',');

        point.Latitude = double.Parse(digits[0].Trim());
        point.Longitude = double.Parse(digits[1].Trim());

        reverseGeocodeRequest.Location = point;

        // Make the reverse geocode request
        GeocodeServiceClient geocodeService = new GeocodeServiceClient();
        GeocodeResponse geocodeResponse = geocodeService.ReverseGeocode(reverseGeocodeRequest);

        if (geocodeResponse.Results.Length > 0)
            results = geocodeResponse.Results[0].DisplayName;
        else
            results = "No Results found";

        return results;
    }

    private string SearchKeywordLocation(string keywordLocation)
    {
        String results = "";
        String key = "Validate Bing Map Education Code";
        SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest();

        // Set the credentials using a valid Bing Maps key
        searchRequest.Credentials = new SearchService.Credentials();
        searchRequest.Credentials.ApplicationId = key;

        //Create the search query
        StructuredSearchQuery ssQuery = new StructuredSearchQuery();
        string[] parts = keywordLocation.Split(';');
        ssQuery.Keyword = parts[0];
        ssQuery.Location = parts[1];
        searchRequest.StructuredQuery = ssQuery;

        //Define options on the search
        searchRequest.SearchOptions = new SearchOptions();
        searchRequest.SearchOptions.Filters =
            new FilterExpression()
            {
                PropertyId = 3,
                CompareOperator = CompareOperator.GreaterThanOrEquals,
                FilterValue = 8.16
            };

        //Make the search request 
        SearchServiceClient searchService = new SearchServiceClient();
        SearchResponse searchResponse = searchService.Search(searchRequest);

        //Parse and format results
        if (searchResponse.ResultSets[0].Results.Length > 0)
        {
            StringBuilder resultList = new StringBuilder("");
            for (int i = 0; i < searchResponse.ResultSets[0].Results.Length; i++)
            {
                resultList.Append(String.Format("{0}. {1}\n", i + 1,
                    searchResponse.ResultSets[0].Results[i].Name));
            }

            results = resultList.ToString();
        }
        else
            results = "No results found";

        return results;
    }



    private void Geocode_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        labelResults.Content = GeocodeAddress(textInput.Text);
    }

    private void ReverseGeocode_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        labelResults.Content = ReverseGeocodePoint(textInput.Text);
    }

    private void Search_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        labelResults.Content = SearchKeywordLocation(textInput.Text);
    }

}
}
```

I found the solution line 62 should be:

```
var geocodeService = new GeocodeServiceClient("BasicHttpBinding_IGeocodeService");
```

Comment: did you add the 4 Service References to your project?

Comment: Yes I did add the 4 service references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your web.config file or app.config file. In there you will see a basic and custom binding configuration for the service. Remove the custom binding section. Clean and build your project and it should work.

As a side note. The Bing Maps SOAP services are really old and limited in functionality. They were released about 8 years ago. A newer REST based service was released about 4 years ago. REST is faster, has smaller response packages and has more features. You can find out more about the Bing Maps REST services here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701713.aspx